# In javascript, prototype, how do you dynamically click a button that had just been clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, prototype

Let's say I have..

```
<button id="pm_Update">Save Changes - Stay on this page</button>
```

Then I click it, is there a code that will dynamically click it again?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample (using jQuery) to click the button after specific period of time..

```
$(function () {
  $("#pm_Update").click(function (e) {
    // DO-SOMETHING

    //click it after specifed period of time
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      $("#pm_Update").click();
    }, 1000); //timeout in milliseconds
  }
});
```